# In JQuery, how do I copy a subset of select options from one select menu to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, copying, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm using JQuery 1.11.1.  I have two select menu elements, one containing options like

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="A">option A</option>
    <option value="B">option B</option>
    ...
    <option value="">=============</option>
    <option value="AA">option AA</option>
    <option value="BB">option BB</option>
    ...
</select>
```

How do I copy the options up to and including the option with the 
"=============" text to the second select menu (let's say the second select menu has id='select2').

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var option, count = -1;
while ((option = $('#select1 option')[++count]).value != "")
{
  $(option).clone().appendTo('#select2');
}
$($('#select1 option')[count]).clone().appendTo('#select2'); //for the '=====' one
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
    <option value="A">option A</option>
    <option value="B">option B</option>
    <option value="">=============</option>
    <option value="AA">option AA</option>
    <option value="BB">option BB</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
</select>
```

Comment: Not related to the actual approach, just a few comments on optimization and readability.  You should really cache that jquery object instead of re-querying the DOM on every iteration of the loop.  You could also consider using jquery's `.eq` to get the element instead of unwrapping and re-wrapping the elements.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

You can do it this way:

```
var emptyOption = $("#select1 option").filter(function() {
                     return $.trim( $(this).val() ) == '';
                  });
var $options = emptyOption.prevAll().addBack().clone();
$('#select2').append($options);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inanda/uosvokdr/2/

**Second solution:**

If you can add a class to the options you want to copy, you can do it the following way.

HTML

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="A" class="copy">option A</option>
    <option value="B" class="copy">option B</option>

    <option value="" class="copy">=============</option>
    <option value="AA">option AA</option>
    <option value="BB">option BB</option>

</select>

<select id="select2">
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var $options = $("#select1 > option.copy").clone();

$('#select2').append($options);
```

Working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inanda/m2qd177u/1/

Comment: Good start but you left out the `<option value="">=============</option>`

Comment: You shouldn't use `andSelf` as it has been deprecated as of 1.8.  You should use `addBack` which is the replacement and works the same.  You can also simplify your initial line to just `var emptyOption = $("#select1 option[value='']");` and eliminate the need for `filter`  (though this won't handler the `trim` you have added to yours)

Comment: Yep, that's why I added the filter. I don't know how he is creating this HTML. Better to prevent issues in the case that I don't know. But if you are sure it's never gonna need the trim, then it would be simpler.